# Check dynamic web page is modified

Tags: http, redirect

I want to check if page https://m.nn.ru/f/1238 has been updated periodically.
I ran
curl https://m.nn.ru/f/1238 | head -c 4096
And it's output is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://passport.ngs.ru/check/?name=ngs_token&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2Fm.nn.ru%2Ff%2F1238" />
    
            <title>Redirecting to https://passport.ngs.ru/check/?name=ngs_token&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2Fm.nn.ru%2Ff%2F1238</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Redirecting to <a href="https://passport.ngs.ru/check/?name=ngs_token&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2Fm.nn.ru%2Ff%2F1238">https://passport.ngs.ru/check/?name=ngs_token&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2Fm.nn.ru%2Ff%2F1238</a>.
     </body>
</html>
```

So I am redirected to login page and brought back to m.nn.ru/f/1238
When I open m.nn.ru/f/1238 in browser it doesn't show the redirection link but the contents of m.nn.ru/f/1238 (though I am not logged in and I think there are no cookies set)
How to get the contents of https://m.nn.ru/f/1238 ?

Another alternative is to use https://nn.ru/community/hobby/advance which has a 301 redirect

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I installed elinks text-mode browser and save the page:
elinks https://m.nn.ru/f/1238 > 1